# Jquery dynamically selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to select the child element of an ID that is evaluated dynamically in jquery, but the code is not working. Where do you think is the mistake?
data_id is dynamically.

```
 $("#duplicater" + data_id + ".chat_box_right_button_collapse").toggleClass("show");
```

Comment: Can you please show, How your element looks like?

Comment: If you're trying to select the child with that class, then you're missing the space before the `.`

Comment: I think you are missing a space or a ' > ' , depending on whether you want to select all descendants or only direct children of `#duplicater[data_id]`

Comment: `".chat_box` -> `" .chat_box`

Answer (score 1):

In your code there is no space between your dynamic id and class name(before dot). Please check this and compare with your one

```
$("#duplicater" + data_id + " .chat_box_right_button_collapse").toggleClass("show");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use template literals

```
$(`#duplicater${data_id} .chat_box_right_button_collapse`).toggleClass("show");
```

Answer (score 1):

If your child element is the element with a class of `chat_box_right_button_collapse`, then try with a space for the CSS selector :

```js
$("#duplicater" + data_id + " .chat_box_right_button_collapse").toggleClass("show");
```

If your child element is a direct child, you can also use the `>` selector :

```js
$("#duplicater" + data_id + " > .chat_box_right_button_collapse").toggleClass("show");
```